# I am trying to print a simple triangle with JavaScript in Chrome, but similar items are grouped as one

Tags: javascript, console, pattern-matching

I am new to JavaScript, and I'm currently learning how to print messages in consoles with the help of *for* and *while* loops.

I am just trying to print patterns starting with a simple triangle for which I wrote the following program.

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i =i+1)
     {
       for(let j=0;j<=i; j=j+1)
         {
           console.log("#");
         }
     }
```

This the output I currently need.

```
   #

   ##

   ###

   ####

   #####
```

But when the script runs, the browser groups similar items as one.

The console shows output like this:

```
`21 #`
```

I tried unchecking the group similar items in the settings and also turned on the timestamps, but I am not able get the pattern. How can I fix this?

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIimw.png)

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoBOp.png)

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh6YT.png)

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77732764/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is due to the way the `console.log` function works in JavaScript. Each call to `console.log` outputs a new line in the console, which is why you're seeing each `#` on a separate line. To create the pattern you're aiming for, you need to build a string for each row of your triangle and then print that string. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let row = '';
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        row += '#';
    }
    console.log(row);
}
```

In this revised version of your code, the inner loop (`for (let j = 0; j < i; j++)`) constructs a string `row` by concatenating `#` characters. The number of `#` characters added to `row` is determined by the current value of `i` from the outer loop. After the inner loop completes for each iteration of `i`, the `row` string (which now contains `i` number of `#` characters) is printed to the console.

This will produce the output:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

Each line corresponds to one iteration of the outer loop, with the inner loop determining how many `#` characters are in each line. This approach ensures that the entire pattern is printed correctly in the console.

Comment: Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you vet this content beforehand. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

console.log() will print a new entry onto the console every time you call it. For what you are trying to do, you should try this:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i =i+1)   
{
  console.log("#".repeat(i));
}
```